# Загрузка аватара

Tags: php, mysql

Люди, пожалуйста, помогите сделать загрузку аватара в таблицу пользователя. Есть скрипт, но он при загрузке изображения создает нового пользователя, а надо, что бы имя рисунка записывалось в графу пользователя, допустим, "avatar" или "userimage".

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста: 1) какие у вас знания в php, 2) исходник скрипта загрузки бы не помешал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем виде решение выглядит так:

Создать в таблице пользователей поле  "avatar"

После загрузки файла и всех проверок делать

```
$userID = 15; // получить ИД пользователя, загрузившего аватар
$file = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/', $uploadedFilePath); // получить путь вида '/img/avatars/15.jpg'
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='$file' WHERE id='$userID';");`
```

Answer (score 2):

Присоединяясь к вышесказанному посту, хочу лишь дополнить, что узнать id только что добавленной записи в рамках текущего соединения с mysql можно с помощью запроса

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Так вы узнаете user_id.

Comment: ...или функцией <a href="http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php">mysql_insert_id()</a> из PHP.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста,а как сделать что бы фотку загружал именно авторизованный пользователь и в свою таблицу.Например в примере изложенном выше,написано $userID = 15. Так вот как изменить что бы была загрузка аватара не пятнадцатому пользователю а именно тому юзеру, который авторизован. $userID = $userID, $userID = $ID, не подходит.(и все в точности наоборот, тоже не подходит.) Заранее СПАСИБО за отзывчивость !!!

Comment: Обычно на сервере хранится таблица пользователей. Допустим, три столбика: user_id,login,password.
При авторизации по введенному login (с проверкой пароля) вы извлекаете из базы user_id.